# Knex.js Data Type Conversion

Tags: sql-server, knex.js, zod, tedious, js-joda

I'm using zod, knex.js, Tedious, and js-joda with MS SQL Server. I want to pull a few columns as the appropriate js-joda type. For example, `start_date` is a `date` and I want it to be deserialized as a LocalDateTime (and vice versa). I'm just not sure how to get either knex.js or tedious to customize the data type returned, it's always a JS Date, which is inappropriate.

I have the code fairly encapsulated, so currently my best bet *feels* like just writing my `getAll` or `getOne` function with a pipe through my zod type's parse method...but it feels like knex or tedious *should* have a way to customize a given column's deserializer.

Comment: Half of the answer is the ingoing parameter bindings that I missed the first time through the docs: https://knexjs.org/guide/#configuration-options  But this is only the serialization step, not the deserialization step.